# Passing a method to another method for Hangfire Scheduler instead of using a hardcoded method name

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am using Hangfire and trying to just schedule a simple job. It works if I hardcode the name of the method to be triggered at the specified time, but I would like something more generic, i.e. to pass any method into this code and let Hangfire execute it on schedule.

Here's one of the ways I tried to do it.

```
public static void ScheduleSingleRun(Activity parametersStorage, Action<Activity, int> scheduledFunction, int secondsDelay)
{
    TimeSpan offset = new TimeSpan(0, 0, secondsDelay);
    try
    {
        BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => 
            scheduledFunction(parametersStorage, secondsDelay), offset);
        return new HangfireSchedulerResponse("Scheduled successfully.", 0);          
        ...
```

And here is how I call this function:

```
HangfireScheduler.ScheduleSingleRun(parameters, TestMethod, 15);
```

Where TestMethod is the name of a method in the same class.

This code compiles, but causes this error when running:

```
Expression body should be of type `MethodCallExpression`"
```

I tried Action, Func<>, Delegate - nothing worked. Only specifying the explicit method name works:

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => TestClass.TestMethod(parametersStorage, secondsDelay)
```

What am I doing wrong - is there a way to just pass a method name/reference to Hangfire instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: Just looking at the exception I think you should pass something like: 
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(...);

Basically you have to pass an Expression. Create your own expression tree manually and pass it. more info here => https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Dynamically Create Method from String for Lambda Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411278/how-to-dynamically-create-method-from-string-for-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example below. In your case I think you have to pass an expression. In my example you should pass "lambda" variable to your BackgroundJob.Schedule method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int param1Value = 2;
        object param2Value = "hello";

        var param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
        var param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));

        var testMethodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("TestMethod", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        var exp = Expression.Call(testMethodInfo, param1, param2);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<int, object>>(exp, param1, param2);

        lambda.Compile().Invoke(param1Value, param2Value);
    }
}

static class MyClass
{
    public static void TestMethod(int param1, object param2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(param1);
        Console.WriteLine(param2?.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: just one things, because by default, Reflection will only search for public methods, it doesn't need to pass BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31388963/1393052